# Composition of $C^k$ functions is $C^k$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the composition of class $C^k$ functions also of class $C^k$?

I feel like this one should be true but I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a consequence of the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), which allows us to calculate $(f\circ g)^{(k)}$ in terms of $f,f',\ldots,f^{(k)},g,g',\ldots,g^{(k)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is true..  If $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ function, we have 
$$d(f\circ g)_x=  d f_{g(x)}\circ dg_x$$

so we have $f\circ g$ is also $C^1$, Now take $f'$ and $g'$ which is also $C^1$, you will have for $h=f'\circ g'$, $h'$ is also $C^1$... proceed inductively... you will get.

Comment: Why does this show that $f\circ g$ is $C^1$? Can you please explain why $f\circ g$ is $C^1$ from this analysis?