# Finding the range of $f(x)=\log_2\left(4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}\right)$

Tags: optimization, logarithms, exponential-function, maxima-minima

> If the range of the function $f(x)=\log_2\left(4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}\right)$ is $\left(\frac pq,\infty\right)$, where $p, q$ are in their lowest form then find $(p+q), (p-q)$

Looks like the domain is $\mathbb R$.

If $x^2=0$, $(x-1)^2=1\implies f(0)=\log_2\left(1+4\right)=\log_25$

If $(x-1)^2=0, x^2=1\implies f(1)=\log_25$

So, I think $p=\log_25, q=1$

So, $p+q=\log_25+1, p-q=\log_25-1$

But the options are $1/3/4/5/10$.

I tried converting the base to $10$ and writing $5$ as $10/2$ but in vain.

Comment: Is the left parentheses in the interval $\left(\frac{p}{q},\infty\right)$ a typo? Looking at a graph of the function, it seems like the image should be of the form $\left[\frac{p}{q},\infty\right)$.

Comment: You have computed $f(0)=f(1) = \log_2 5$, but that is not necessarily the minimum. I would suggest to *plot* the function to get some ideas.

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of the problem? Actually, the range of $f$ is $\left[\frac32,\infty\right)$, and therefore it's not of the form $\left(\frac pq,\infty\right)$. Besides, $\frac32=\frac64=\frac96=\cdots$. That is $p$ and $q$ are not unique, an so it makes no sense to talk about the values of $p\pm q$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Unless I am mistaken, the lower bound is $f(1/2) = 3/2$.

Comment: @MartinR No, you're not mistaken. I've edited my comment.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I have made the edit.

Comment: @AlannRosas the statement has round bracket and not square brackets. But looking at the comments, I too think there should be square brackets.

Comment: So, since $\frac pq=\frac32$, $p+q=4$ and $p-q=1$.

Comment: @MartinR now that you have mentioned $f(1/2)$, I too think this would be the minimum and I should have checked it. But this is hit and try. You have suggested to plot the function. Can you elaborate on that? I mean can we draw the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Jensen for the convex function $f(x)=4^{x^2}$ we obtain:
$$4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}\geq2\cdot4^{\left(\frac{x+1-x}{2}\right)^2}=2\sqrt2.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Hi. I think you have used AM$\ge GM$. And GM$=4^{\frac{x^2+(x-1)^2}2}$. How did you write $\left(\frac{x+1-x}2\right)^2$?

Comment: @aarbee I used Jensen for the convex function $f$: $f(a)+f(b)\geq 2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$. Now, take $f(x)=4^{x^2},$ $a=x$ and $b=1-x.$

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an error in the statement of the problem, since the range of $f$ is of the form $\left[\frac pq,\infty\right)$.

Anyway,$$f'(x)=4\left(x-\frac1{1+4^{2x-1}}\right).$$Since $x\mapsto x$ is strictly increasing and $x\mapsto\frac1{1+4^{2x-1}}$ is strictly decreasing, $f'(x)$ has at most one zero. But it's clear that $f'\left(\frac12\right)=0$. It follows from what I wrote that $f'(x)<0$ if $x<\frac12$ and that $f'(x)>0$ if $x>\frac12$. So, the minimum of $f$ is attained at $\frac12$. Since $f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac32$ and since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\infty$, the range of $f$ is $\left[\frac32,\infty\right)$. So, $p=3$, and $q=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}$ is strictly positive on $\mathbb R$, so taking $\log_2$ of it is well defined everywhere on $\mathbb R$. Moreover it is a [composition of continuously differentiable ($C^1$) functions hence $C^1$ on $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114685/composition-of-ck-functions-is-ck). As $x\to \infty$ and $x\to-\infty$, $4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}$ goes to $\infty$, so $f$ goes to $\infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$. With this information plus the fact that $f$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb R$, we know that the (global) minimum of $f$ is attained at some $x_0$ and $x_0$ satisfies $f'(x_0)= 0$. You can compute this yourself and find $x_0$. Lastly, continuity means that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value property, so indeed $f$ hits EVERY value $\geq f(x_0)$, meaning the range is $[f(x_0),\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\begin{align}4^{x^2}+4^{{(x-1)}^2}
&≥2\sqrt{4^{x^2+(x-1)^2}}\\
&=2^{{x^2+(x-1)^2}+1}\\
&≥2^{2\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 32}\\
&≥2^{\frac 32}\end{align}$$

$$\log_2\left(4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}\right)≥\log_2{2^{\frac 32}}=\frac 32.$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have that by $x=u+\frac12$ and AM-GM

$$g(x)=4^{x^2}+4^{(x-1)^2}=4^{\left(u+\frac12\right)^2}+4^{\left(u-\frac12\right)^2}=$$

$$=h(u)=4^{\left(u^2+\frac14\right)}\left(4^u+4^{-u}\right)\ge 2\sqrt 2$$

with $h(u):\mathbb R \to [2\sqrt 2, \infty)$ even and increasing and since also $\log_2$ function is ingreasing we can conclude that $$f(x)\ge \log_2 2\sqrt 2=\frac32$$